# Xcode Label Line Break Not working when opening the app from iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints, line-breaks

In my app labels line breaks are working fine only if the app is connected to the xcode. If I disconnect the app from xcode and open the app from iPhone the line breaks are not working. Please see below screenshots.
[image]

This screenshot is taken when the app is running from the xcode. As you can see the line breaks are working fine in this scenario.But if I stopped running the app from xcode and open the app from the phone, look at the below screenshot. Line breaks are not working. What could be the reason for this?

[image]

Comment: Would you please share the code that you have tried?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed I did this on the storyboard. I have added constraints for all sides in the labels and set number of lines to 0. The Line break option is set as Truncate Tail. I tried with the word wrap also. But didn't work.

Comment: Would you please set the linenumber programatically?